# How to Combine Union and Order By

Tags: sql

i am trying to query my schema but im getting the following error:

error:

```
SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.
```

query:

```
 select 'select M1.Batchno,M1.Tranno,M1.SeqNo,M1.insertseqno,M1.CaptureBatchNo,M1.CaptureSeqNo,
M1.TranType,M1.itemtype,M1.RtNo,M1.AccountNo,M1.CheckSerial,M1.Amount 
from (select distinct batchno,tranno from ' + table_name+  ') M inner join '
+ table_name+ ' M1 on M.BatchNo=M1.Batchno and M.TranNo = M1.TranNo 
inner join rps..ProcDate pd
on pd.pdkey = m1.pdkey
and pd.jobkey = 5 order by M1.Batchno,M.TranNo,M1.Seqno union ' 
 from information_schema.tables where table_name like '%micrinfo2101%' order by TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: The query that you have only has `union` in a string.  It is hard to see how that could cause an error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff there's TWO order by. One inside the string it doesnt work but the ORDER by Table_name does work.

Comment: Gordon is right.  You have `select 'select...'`.  Everything inside the quotes is just a string constant.  That's not how you do a nested query.

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to accomplish here.  The two parts of a union have to have the same number of fields.  Even if you moved the SELECT to after the UNION, this query still wouldn't make sense.  It is two totally unrelated queries.

Comment: Where do "rps" and "pd" come from?  I think you have a cut-and-paste problem here.

Comment: @TimRoberts the select outside the query lets me query my schema so i can replace table_name with the schema that is like "%micrinfo01%. I took out the order by clause and put the results in excel. I was able to filter batchno, tranno, and seqno using excel.

Comment: rps and pd are tables that have relation with my table in the schema "micrinfo2101".

Comment: So, is the object of this statement to produce an SQL statement as a string, that you can turn around and feed in as another query?  That's odd.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error while trying to execute the statement you are preparing from information_schema.tables. Remove union since there is no query in the right side of union

```
select 'select M1.Batchno,M1.Tranno,M1.SeqNo,M1.insertseqno,M1.CaptureBatchNo,M1.CaptureSeqNo,
M1.TranType,M1.itemtype,M1.RtNo,M1.AccountNo,M1.CheckSerial,M1.Amount 
from (select distinct batchno,tranno from ' + table_name+  ') M inner join '
+ table_name+ ' M1 on M.BatchNo=M1.Batchno and M.TranNo = M1.TranNo 
inner join rps..ProcDate pd
on pd.pdkey = m1.pdkey
and pd.jobkey = 5 order by M1.Batchno,M.TranNo,M1.Seqno ' 
 from information_schema.tables where table_name like '%micrinfo2101%' order by TABLE_NAME
```

Or if you are creating a dynamic SQL with union for all the tables like **micrinfo2101** then use below query:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT 'UNION' + ' select M1.Batchno,M1.Tranno,M1.SeqNo,M1.insertseqno,M1.CaptureBatchNo,M1.CaptureSeqNo,
M1.TranType,M1.itemtype,M1.RtNo,M1.AccountNo,M1.CheckSerial,M1.Amount 
from (select distinct batchno,tranno from ' + table_name+  ') M inner join '
+ table_name+ ' M1 on M.BatchNo=M1.Batchno and M.TranNo = M1.TranNo 
inner join rps..ProcDate pd
on pd.pdkey = m1.pdkey
and pd.jobkey = 5 order by M1.Batchno,M.TranNo,M1.Seqno '
            from information_schema.tables where table_name like '%EMPLOYEE%' order by TABLE_NAME 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,5,'')
```